# Yii 1.0 sb admin theme navigation

Tags: php, css, yii, themes, admin

this may seem like a basic question but I wanted to integrate the sb admin theme to my yii site and this is the first time I've tried this so be gentle...

so I set the sbadmin up to be like a yii theme so I can use the `'theme'=> 'sbadmin'` on my main.php and I got it working but the navigation wont seem to cooperate with me

```
<div class="nav navbar-right">
  <?php $this->widget('zii.widgets.CMenu',array(
    'htmlOptions'=>array('class'=>'pull-right nav'),
    'submenuHtmlOptions'=>array('class'=>'dropdown-menu'),
    'itemCssClass'=>'item-test',
    'encodeLabel'=>false,
    'items'=>array(
        array('label'=>'Home', 'url'=>array('/site/index')),
        array('label'=>'Dashboard', 'url'=>array('/site/dashboard'), 'visible' => Yii::app()->user->isAdmin()),
        array('label'=>'Dashboard', 'url'=>array('/site/dashboard2'), 'visible' => Yii::app()->user->isUser()),
        array('label'=>'Login', 'url'=>array('/site/login'), 'visible'=>Yii::app()->user->isGuest),
        array('label'=>'Register', 'url'=>array('/user/registration'), 'visible'=>Yii::app()->user->isGuest),
        array('label'=>'Logout ('.Yii::app()->user->name.')', 'url'=>array('/site/logout'), 'visible'=>!Yii::app()->user->isGuest)
     ),
  )); ?>
```

so basically this code displays the navigation but it is displayed like this: [image]

All my CSS files came from the sb admin theme so I was wondering why it displayed that way. Does it have something to do with the yii codes? how can I fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try using

```
'htmlOptions'=>array('class'=>'pull-right nav navbar'),
```

or

```
'htmlOptions'=>array('class'=>'pull-right nav navbar-inner'),
```